# Web.xml - not redirecting specific file or url to servlet

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, servlets, web.xml

I want to redirect all connections (`/*`) to a specific servlet, except a specific file (`someFile.xml`).

I have the following section in web.xml:

```
<servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>someServlet</servlet-name> 
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

How can I modify it so that `/someFile.xml` will not be mapped to this servlet.

If I cannot do it using `web.xml`, is there some other way?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a Servlet and map it to receive /someFile.xml.

```
    <servlet-mapping>
          <servlet-name>someServlet</servlet-name> 
          <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
           <servlet-name>SomeFileServlet</servlet-name> 
           <url-pattern>/someFile.xml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

In this way all request except /someFile.xml will go to someServlet and request for /someFile.xml will go to SomeFileServlet.

```
**/* mapping in web.xml it answers all requests except other path mappings.**
```

Comment: Fair, this is a good solution and it should work like a charm!

Comment: I don't want to redirect to another servlet. I want someFile.xml to be retrieved as is by the apache

Comment: @ErikSapir do u have apache http server?? by apache did u meant tat ? if yes you have to look into apache rewrite rules.